# How to create view with joining non-index value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I have table tcmcs008 as:

```
curr|excb|rate|rapr
USD |1   |0.77|2
AUD |1   |0.68|1
INR |2   |1   |1
:
:
```

Index is curr.
And another table with the descriptions of enum fields for different tables as:

```
tabl    |fild|valu|dscr
tcmcs008|excb|1   |Yes
tcmcs008|excb|2   |No
tcmcs008|rapr|1   |Yes
tcmcs008|rapr|2   |No
tcibd001|type|1   |Purchase Item
tcibd001|type|2   |Cost Item
tcibd001|type|3   |Manufactured item
:
:
```

index is tabl    |fild|valu

I want to create a view for tcibd008(and for other tables as well) such as:

```
curr|excb  |rate|rapr
USD |Yes   |0.77|No
AUD |Yes   |0.68|Yes
INR |No    |1   |Yes
:
:
```

I could do this with hardcoding as:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW A_tcmcs008060 As 
SELECT t.ccur, 
       CASE WHEN t.excb = 1 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END, 
       rate,
       CASE WHEN t.rapr = 1 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END
FROM ttcmcs008060 t
```

Can anyone please help to achieve this using table join or any other way?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW A_tcmcs008060 As 
    SELECT t.ccur, e.dscr, t.rate
    FROM ttcmcs008060 t LEFT JOIN
         enums e
         ON t.excb = e.valu and e.fild = 'excb';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But 'excb' is still hardcoded. One more thing is for a table there can be multiple enum fields. The query I have shown here is just for example sake. In reality, we may need all of them.

Comment: Even if we go for hardcoding as e.fild = 'excb' how to get dscr for both excb as well as rapr?

Comment: @sweenal . . . The question in your comment should be asked as a *new* question, with sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what results you want.